# How to git diff at once all modified files which are not (yet) staged?

Tags: git, git-diff

`git diff --staged` shows differences on already `staged` files.

Question: How to `git diff` at once all `modified` files which are not (yet) staged?

For example:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   f1.c
        modified:   f2.c
        modified:   f3.c
```

How to `git diff` at once all `modified` files here? I.e. `git diff` at once `f1.c`, `f2.c`, `f3.c`.

Comment: Doesn't `git diff` do just that?

Comment: It should, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971046/how-to-git-diff-at-once-all-modified-files-which-are-not-yet-staged#comment116641294_65971046) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971046/how-to-git-diff-at-once-all-modified-files-which-are-not-yet-staged#comment116642062_65971046), `git diff` with no additional arguments does this already.

It's worth pointing out something else here, though.  In particular, Git has, at all times,<sup>1</sup> *three* of what I call "active copies" of each file.  Let's say that you have, in your *current* commit, those three files you mention above, plus files named `README.md` and `LICENSE.md`.  There are therefore five files in the *current commit:*

- `README.md`
- `LICENSE.md`
- `f1.c`
- `f2.c`
- `f3.c`

These five files are "active" in that they're sitting there *in* that current commit, available for you to compare against what you're doing right now, or to use `git reset --hard` to put everything back to the way it is in those five files, for instance.

Meanwhile, those five files have been *copied into Git's index.*<sup>2</sup>  You cannot *see* these copies,<sup>3</sup> but they exist.  In fact, they're the copies that will go into your *next commit* once you make it.  The `git add` command is about *updating these copies*, which initially match the copies from the current commit.  So Git's index has the same five files in it, until you start running `git add` anyway: that copies new files in, displacing the previous copies, or copies all-new files into Git's index, adding a sixth file, for instance.

Finally, there are ordinary everyday copies of the five files.  They are in what Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  These are *yours*, to do with as you will: Git copied them *out* of the commit—first into Git's index, then into your working tree—when you ran `git checkout`,<sup>4</sup> and from then on, you get to do whatever you like with them.  If you've *changed* them, and want those updates to go into your next commit, you'll need to run `git add`, which will copy the updates back into Git's index, updating the index copy to match your work-tree copy.

When you run `git status`, this command:

- prints out helpful stuff like which branch name you're on, then
- runs one comparison: the one you see with `git diff --staged`; then
- runs one more comparison: the one you see with `git diff` with no extra options.

The two `git diff`s are the ones of interest here:

- The first compares all the (in this case five) files in the *current commit*—`HEAD:README.md`, `HEAD:LICENSE.md`, and so on—to all the files in Git's index.  When those two files *match*, `git status` says nothing at all.  When they're *different* in some way, `git status` prints the name of the file, under the category `staged for commit`.
- The second `git diff` compares all the files in Git's index to all the same-named files in your working tree.  Wherever these two are *the same*, Git says nothing; where they're *different*, it says that this file is `not staged for commit`.

Note that it's possible to have all three copies different.  Check out some commit, so that all five (or whatever count) files are the same.  Modify your copy of one of them, and run `git add`.  Now the `HEAD` copy doesn't match the other two, but Git's index copy and your copy do match.  But now modify *your* copy *again*.  All three files are now different, as long as your second change wasn't just to change the file back.  Running `git status` will now show that one file as *both* `staged for commit` *and* `not staged for commit`.

Running `git diff --staged`<sup>5</sup> compares `HEAD` vs index.  Running `git diff` compares index vs work-tree.  There are a whole lot more forms of `git diff` too, such as `git diff commit1 commit2`.  Read through [the `git diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) while thinking about this question: *What should you run if you want to compare the `HEAD` commit vs your current work-tree, skipping right over the index that sits between them?*  (The answer is pretty simple, but try to find it on your own before cheating with footnote 6.<sup>6</sup>)

---

<sup>1</sup>Sometimes, Git has up to *five* copies of each file.  In particular, during a conflicted merge, Git will retrieve copies from three commits and put all three of those into its index.  Rarely—such as when you use `git rm` to remove a file—the number drops below three, but then we get into a metaphysical / philosophy problem that falls into the "if there's no file in the forest, did it make a noise when you cut it down" kind of thing.

<sup>2</sup>Two things are noteworthy here:

1. Git's index has two other names: the *staging area*, and the *cache*.  All three refer to the same thing.
2. What's in the index is not literally a copy of each file, but rather a three-tuple of mode, name, and blob-hash.  This is how Git pre-compresses and pre-de-duplicates files to go into a commit, or shares files with some existing commit.

Still, these things *act like* copies of the file, so it's probably simplest to just think of them as being copies.  You'll only be able to tell the difference if you start using the commands mentioned in footnote 3.

<sup>3</sup>You actually *can* see them, sort of.  Run `git ls-files --stage` to dump out the index contents.  Be aware that this produces one line of output per staged file, *including* files that `git status` would silently skip over because they're staged but *not modified*.  The "file in staging = file in commit" situation is *why* `git status` *doesn't* talk about the file.  If you're working on a big project with tens of thousands of files, you're probably not very interested in the 29997 files that *aren't* changed; you only care about the 3 files that *are*.  It's fine to run `git ls-files`, which only *looks* at all the staged files, but when it outputs 30000 lines of file information, that's not all that helpful.

The `git update-index` command is a similar extremely-low-level command that lets you manipulate the index copies of files directly.  Since this *does* write on the index, it takes a little bit more care when using it, but it does have some very special-purpose uses.

<sup>4</sup>Git makes use of the stuff in its index to optimize the checkout.  Suppose you're on commit `a123456`, for instance, because you ran `git checkout main` or whatever.  You then run `git checkout dev` which picks commit `b789abc` to check out.  There's a really good chance that out of 30000 files in Git's index and your working tree, 29735 or so of them are *the same* in these two commits, leaving only 256 *different* files.  The checkout command can leave all the unchanged files in place, in both Git's index and your work-tree, updating only the remaining files.  This is *much* faster.

For those of us used to older version control systems, when we first ran `git checkout` and got a prompt back right away instead of a five minute break, we thought Git was broken.   This index thing is pretty clever.  It does make for a very long side trip when you're first getting used to Git, though.

<sup>5</sup>`git diff --cached` and `git diff --staged` do exactly the same single thing: `--cached` and `--staged` are synonyms here.  The `--cached` flag refers to the third name of the index, the *cache*.  This same name pops up in `git rm --cached`.  For some reason, there is still no `--staged` synonym in `git rm`.  Git commands are not very consistent here, mostly for historical reasons.

<sup>6</sup>`git diff HEAD`.  (Now, what if you want to compare what's in the index / staging-area right now, vs some specific commit?)

Comment: Do we get a footnote 6-1 giving the answer to the footnote exercise??? :)

Comment: @matt: nope! though I see I accidentally left out the hyphen in `commit-2`, and now I wonder if I should take out the hyphen in `commit-1`...

Comment: Have you thought of publishing a book [1] containing such detailed [2] SO answers? Or is there an initiative in SO community to create such a book [1]? [1] Or series of books. [2] Maybe not your answers only.